# Is there another keyboard shortcut for cycling command history in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I know you can use the arrow keys to go up and down the command history in bash but I want to know if there is equivalent letter-based shortcut so my hands don't have to travel as far. Any ideas?

Note: I'm aware of Ctrl-R for searching command history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **bash** most of the **emacs** key-bindings works as well.

So what you are looking for here is, <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd>

Or, you can do `set -o vi`  and then use the **vi** key-bindings  <kbd>j</kbd> & <kbd>k</kbd>. In normal mode of course,i.e. do, <kbd>ESC</kbd> first.

Comment: You can set the default key bindings if you like.  I think emacs is the default (`set -o emacs`), but you can also do `set -o vi` if you want vi-like key bindings.

Comment: if you use the vi bindings, do you prefix j & k with ctrl or another key?

Comment: @trinth I had to use the `alt` key after turning on vi option; whilst by default (emacs ON) I used `ctrl` key.

Comment: @trinth: if you are using the vi mode then just press ESC to go to the normal mode and then use j/k :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing about ctrl-R I didn't know was that you can hit it a second/third/... time to scroll back through previous matching commands.  I can't believe that all these year I'd been doing `history | grep blah` instead.